# Coldfusion 10 lockdown guide 401.3 error on isapi_redirect.dll

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server-2008, coldfusion-10

I just setup a new W2K8 server with CF10.  I'm going through the Adobe lockdown guide and hitting a problem on pages 29-30 (where you're setting permissions on {coldfusion home}.

I removed the default inherited permissions and set the following:

```
{coldfusion-home} - Administrators - Full Control
{coldfusion-home} - cfusion - Full Control (this is the service account)
{coldfusion-home}/config/wsconfig/ - IUSR, iisservice - list & read
{coldfusion-home}/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE -  IUSR, iisservice - list & read
```

I also granted write on isapi_redirect.log to iisservice as suggested

Now when I open the administrator I get a 401.3 unauthorized ACL error and the physical path points to the \wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll

If I go back and reset the default permissions inherited from the drive, it works fine.

Is the lockdown guide saying "leave the defaults and just add these four", or "remove all defaults, add these 4 settings"?

Comment: What's your effective permissions for the `cfusion` users on that file? It should have inherited "Full Control", based on the info you've given above, but just check that it can actually see it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Authenticated User group that needs read permissions on isapi_redirect.dll.  I've been playing with adding/using permissions and got it down to just the CF10 user and Administrators with full control, and then just Authenticated Users on that file.